Setting up denoise light group help
I've created light groups and I need to render sequence (60 frames) in multilayer EXR with denoised passes.
Is it correct setup and is it possible to render this sequence in blender?
This setup works only for  Single render (F12) but I need sequence (Ctrl + F12).
When I try to render animation and check first frames denoise doesn't work.
Also I've got incorrect colorspace by just setting it in File Output node, so I put Convert Colorspace and it's worked


Found solution by downloading addon Blender_Exr_auto-pass_saver (https://github.com/3d-io/Blender_Exr_auto-pass_saver)
It's automaticaly creates EXR Multilayer node with all enabled passes even light groups in compositing and works perfectly with denoise node and Render Animation
